# Mongoose Middleware in separate scripts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The project I'm working on involves one script connecting to a websocket and updating the database every 6 hours.

I have another script that will use the information in that database, but needs to know when the table has been updated with new data (every 6 hours).

db-script.js

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db-example', function (err) {
        Schema.updateOne({ _id: "some_id"}, {
            data: data
        }, { upsert: true }, (e, r) => {
            if (e) console.log(e);
            console.log(r);
        });
});
```

main-script.js

```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db-example', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        Schema.post('save', function (doc) {
            console.log('just updated', doc._id);
        });
    });//mongoose.connect
```

Is this the correct way to handle such a case? Is there a better way to do so? I could go about simply setting a timeout to query the db every 6 hours, but that would require a reasonable delay which is not ideal.